# Trying to find the index of the first number in a string using perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to find the index of the first occurrence of a number from 0-9.

Let's say that:

```
 $myString = "ABDFSASF9fjdkasljfdkl1"
```

I want to find the position where 9 is.

I've tried this:

```
print index($myString,[0-9]);
```

And:

```
print index($myString,\d);
```

Answer (score 9):

Use regex [Positional Information](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Position-information):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $myString = "ABDFSASF9fjdkasljfdkl1";

if ($myString =~ /\d/) {
    print $-[0];
}
```

Outputs:

```
8
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm assuming that index doesn't work because I was trying to give it a range instead of a substr?

Comment: @ysth :  /\d/a is better than /[0-9]/, because it supports other number formats, like Arabic numbers (initially called indian):  ٠, ١, ٢, ٣, ٤, ٥, ٦, ٧, ٨, ٩ and Indian numbers: ० (0), १ (1), २ (2), etc.

Comment: @AshrafBashir: no, /\d/ does that, /\d/a is the same as /[0-9]/.  and yes, just /\d/ does support other digits; that is the problem.  it is not what most people want or expect in most cases.

Comment: When dealing with multiple languages supporting other digits is very required, and that's what /\d/ does

Answer (score 0):

You can try even below perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $String = "ABDFSASF9fjdkasljfdkl11";

if($String =~ /(\d)/)
 {
     print "Prematch string of first number $1 is $`\n";
     print "Index of first number $1 is " . length($`);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
perl -e '$string="ABDFSASF9fjdkasljfdkl1";@array=split(//,$string);for $i (0..$#array) {if($array[$i]=~/\d/){print $i;last;}}'
```